# For ASP.NET MVC Rescues View, how do we add ViewData fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rescue

I have several Rescues defined for possible faults, however I am unable to access the ViewData to populate it with things we need the masterpage requires to render. Is this hidden away in a controller we can utilize?

Comment: what do you mean by "Rescues"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need ViewData to be made available in the masterpages...  I think that will be a problem since not all the controllers put/assure that data is there.  I'm pretty sure you'd have to have some type of custom controller base to ensure consistent data in all of your controllers.  Try looking into [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221095802/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/scarpenter/archive/2007/12/14/117724.aspx).

I might be wrong but I have seen this question brought up a few times before.